# Not able to upload more the 5GB data on asw s3 using html form

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket, and am using a GitHub S3 class. I am successful in uploading a file which is less then 5GB. But I want to upload more than 5GB data - e.g. 100GB in a single transfer.

```
S3::setAuth(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);    
$bucket = "upload-bucket";
$path = "myfiles/"; // Can be empty ""

$lifetime = 3600; // Period for which the parameters are valid
$maxFileSize = (1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 5); 

$metaHeaders = array("uid" => 123);
$requestHeaders = array(
    "Content-Type" => "application/octet-stream",
    "Content-Disposition" => 'attachment; filename=${filename}'
);

$params = S3::getHttpUploadPostParams(
    $bucket,
    $path,
    S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ,
    $lifetime,
    $maxFileSize,
    201, // Or a URL to redirect to on success
    $metaHeaders,
    $requestHeaders,
    false // False since we're not using flash
);

$uploadURL = "https://{$bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/";



<form method="post" action="<?php echo $uploadURL; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="file" />&#160;<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

I want to upload more the 100GB data through file browser. By using the above code i am able to to upload 5 GB data. But, If i am trying to upload more then 5GB data eg,10Gb,100GB. then this type of error is showing

[image]

Comment: Can you illustrate what you've tried so far with respect to uploading 100GB at a time? Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve if you need a little help learning how to write a question in a way that stack overflow-ers will look at and help you with. If we can't figure out exactly what you're asking you won't get a good response a lot of the time.

Comment: Are you backing up porn? Why would you need to upload 100GB??? Maybe you should change your approach

Comment: I want to upload more the 100GB data through file browser. By using the above code i am able to to upload 5 GB data. But, If i am trying to upload more then 5GB data eg,10Gb,100GB. then this type of error is showing        I want to upload more the 100GB data through file browser. By using the above code i am able to to upload 5 GB data. But, If i am trying to upload more then 5GB data eg,10Gb,100GB. then this type of error is showing
<ERROR>
<code>EntityTooLarge</code>
<PROPOSED>14680363869</PROPOSED>
<MaxSizeAllowed>5368730624</MaxSizeAllowed>

Answer (score 2):

Read [the FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/):

> The largest object that can be uploaded in a single PUT is 5
>   gigabytes. For objects larger than 100 megabytes, customers should
>   consider using the Multipart Upload capability.

You cannot upload file larger that 5 Gb in one request, so you need to develop a solution for chunked ("multipart") upload.